# Google translator stop suddenly while translating data

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate

from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import csv
import requests
input = pd.read_excel(r'C:\AWS\daily.xls')
limit = len(input.index)
for i in range(0, limit):
    translator = Translator()
    a = input.iloc[i, 0]

```
language = translator.detect(a)
#print(language)

if language.lang == 'en':
    print(language.lang)
    print(a)
else:
    translated_comment = translator.translate(a)
    print(language.lang)
    print(a + ' Translate ' + translated_comment.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues with Google translate. If you don't have a token and use the "basic" version, you are limited on the amount of data you can translate.

After that, Google shuts down the connection.

You could use Google Translate and upload a file and translate all by once.

Edit 01/04/2020:

If you go on Google translate webpage, you can see that Google has an aditional button called "Documents". You can upload a txt or doc file and Google will tranlate the contents. For singular use case will work, if you need constant/real time translation then you should get a token from Google

[image]

Comment: I didn't get the last point of uploading a file. I have around 1100 rows in my sheet it translates upto 450 and throws an exception then.